# Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this Hibernate query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hibernate, hql

Below is my query:

```
select c from (select t.*, rownum as rownum_ from t) c 
where rownum_ between :firstResult and :maxResults
```

here `:firstResult` and `:maxResults` are parameters that i am passing to the query.

I am using Oracle 11g Express Edition.

Comment: do you fire it as a native query?

Comment: Which is the error message and or stack trace?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 15 [select c from (select t.*, rownum as rownum_ from t) c where rownum_ between :firstResult and :maxResults]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)

Comment: Yeah its getting fired as native query.

Comment: it should be select *, c is not a column

Comment: I'd be concerned that the optimizer may miss the fact you want a subsection of the results and instead will do a full table scan of `t` to only give you back say the first 25.  I'd rewrite that query as `SELECT rownum as rownum_, t.* FROM t WHERE rownum_ between :firstResult AND :maxResult`

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a table alias here, Not a column asias.

Try :

```
select c.* from (select t.*, rownum as rownum_ from t) c 
where rownum_ between :firstResult and :maxResults
```